# Swift 3 - What error is thrown?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm using Swift's `String`. The reference [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/1414831-init) says it "throws".

So I've got:

```
do {

    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "mydata", ofType: "json")
    let json = try String(contentsOfFile: path!,
                          encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

} catch {

    print ("error")

}
```

It seems to mean it can't find my file. I'll have to check it's actually getting bundled in the target. However, my question is, how would I find out what error has been thrown?

Comment: Remove the double quotes in the `print` statement to get the `error`.

Comment: Also please note that a Swift error that is thrown is *not* an exception. These are different things.

Comment: Thanks, I'll edit the title for accuracy. Comes from living in Java land for so long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the generic Error class to catch it.

```
do {

    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "mydata", ofType: "json")
    let json = try String(contentsOfFile: path!,
                          encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

} catch {
  print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: I modified my answer. Make sure you check the mydata exists in your project.

Comment: That does the trick. I note also the just straight error variable without the .localizedDescription actually seems to provide more useful info on some errors.

Answer (score 2):

You get a free `error` inside your catch block. Just print that variable like:

```
catch {
    print ("error: \(error)")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Create an enum for errors like this:

```
enum calcErrr:Error {
    case notfound
    case readOnly
}


func readJson() throws -> () {
    if let bundlePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "mydata", ofType: "json"),
        let bundle = Bundle(path: bundlePath),
        let path = bundle.path(forResource: "...", ofType: nil) {
        print(path)
    } else {
        throw calcErrr.notfound
    }
}

do {
     try readJson()
}

catch calcErrr.notfound{ print ("Not Found")}
```